# Remove/Rewrite HTTP header 'Server: TwistedWeb'

Tags: python, http-headers, twisted.web

There is some way to remove HTTP Header 'Server: TwistedWeb/13.1.0' from responses from a Twisted based web application?

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite any header by calling the request.setHeader method.

```
class RootPage(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        request.setHeader('server', 'MyVeryOwnServer/1.0')
        return OtherResource(name)
```

Comment: the [format for `server` is not arbitrary](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.38): it should be `token/token token/token ..` e.g., `MyVeryOwnServer/1.0` no spaces/tabs inside a token are allowed.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry, I was concentrating on the question and didn't pay attention (as I should) to other standards.

Answer (score 4):

The change applies to any resources on your site; you could put it in your `Site` class. You want that 404 or 500 errors would also return correct header; so you should set it as earlier as possible but not before it is set by twisted itself (in order to overwrite it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log

class Site(server.Site):
    def getResourceFor(self, request):
        request.setHeader('server', 'Server/1.9E377')
        return server.Site.getResourceFor(self, request)

# example from http://twistedmatrix.com/
class HelloResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    numberRequests = 0

    def render_GET(self, request):
        self.numberRequests += 1
        request.setHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
        return "I am request #" + str(self.numberRequests) + "\n"

log.startLogging(sys.stderr)
reactor.listenTCP(8080, Site(HelloResource()))
reactor.run()
```

Default Server http header is specified in `t.w.server.version`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but if you would like to remove the server http header. I am talking about the

```
request.setHeader('Server', 'SomeServer')
```

This is set by Twisted Web automagically if you don't specify a value. You can remove it by using the inner Headers class. For example,

```
request.responseHeaders.removeHeader('Server')
```

This will remove the Server Http Header.